# Proof of the Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty relation for mixed states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, density-operator, trace

I'm a little stumped by how to show that
$$
V_{\hat{\rho}}(\hat{A})V_{\hat{\rho}}(\hat{B})\ge{\lvert Re(Cov_{\hat{\rho}}(\hat{A},\hat{B})\rvert}^2 + \frac{1}{4}{\lvert Tr\hat{\rho}[\hat{A}\hat{B}]\rvert}^2
$$

for a mixed state, where

$$
Cov_{\hat{\rho}}(\hat{A},\hat{B}) \equiv Tr\hat{\rho}(\hat{A}-{\langle\hat{A}\rangle}_{\hat{\rho}}\hat{I})(\hat{B}-{\langle\hat{B}\rangle}_{\hat{\rho}}\hat{I})
$$

and

$$
V_{\hat{\rho}}(\hat{A}) = Cov_{\hat{\rho}}(\hat{A},\hat{A})
$$

I'm able to do it for a pure state; any help would be greatly appreciated!